# Could not load type 'ServiceStack.IUrlFilter' from assembly 'ServiceStack.Interfaces...'

Tags: servicestack

I am using VS2013 with ServiceStack 4.0.54 just trying to get the ServiceStack ASP.NET MVC5 Empty Template new project to work.  It seems to crash at the line

```
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
```

in Index.cshtml with the error shown in the title.  What else needs to be configured to get this run.

Thanks

My fault -- sorry I had another version of ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll registered in the assembly for my COM interop

It works now -- Thanks -- but it leads me to I guess my real issue -- is there a template that generates the metadata for the operations like the ServiceStack ASP.Net Empty -- as opposed to the "ASP.NET
ASP.NET is a free web framework for building great Web sites and Web applications using HTML, CSS and JavaScript." with the ServiceStack Hello World at the bottom." default page

I want to use the MVC or AngularJS template but with the metadata/operations accessible. Essentially an barebones project.

Thanks again

I got to the metadata Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have dirty dlls as [IUrlFilter is defined in ServiceStack.Interfaces](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/IUrlFilter.cs) which I've just verified using dotPeek is indeed in v4.0.54 of ServiceStack.Interfaces:

[image]

I expect you have some projects referencing an older version of ServiceStack.Interfaces without IUrlFilter. If you can't find which project it is, delete all old (i.e. non v4.0.54) packages from your solutions NuGet `/packages` folder and rebuild to see which projects are broken.

You can verify all projects have been upgraded by closing your solution, deleting the entire NuGet `/packages` folder, re-open your solution and rebuild which should download all NuGet packages again, if there are still ServiceStack packages older than v4.0.54 then you have still have projects referencing older versions that still need to be upgraded.